# How to open new Safari Tab when user perform actions in Popover menu . ?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, safari-extension

i've Created Safari Extension [Created via native way]

[image]

in which , i'm stucked in to open new tab into safari browser

[image: Click on Button : Open New Tab]

onClick of the Button :

```
- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {


[self.sfWindow openTabWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com"] makeActiveIfPossible:true completionHandler:^(SFSafariTab * _Nullable tab) {
    NSLog(@"Naman Vaishnav");

}];}
```

In which I'm getting **self.sfWindow** : null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CFURLRef httpURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("http://"), NULL);
NSLog(@"%@", LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL(httpURL, kLSRolesAll, nil));

NSString *strDefaultBrowser = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL(httpURL, kLSRolesAll, nil)];

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:websiteName]];
```

Comment: Why doesnt this work for me?  I get a ton of errors,  Asking me to put commas or semicolons in weird places.  I am building an extension into Safari and put this in the `SFSafariExtensionViewController`.  My function looks totally different then OP though.  `@IBAction func onSettingsBtnClicked (_ sender: Any) {`